# Invisible corners with shape - Android?

Tags: android-drawable, android-shape, android-shapedrawable, android-graphics

I have bellow `shape` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#434A54" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```

And I have bellow :

[image]

But I see corners yet. How I can invisible them ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#434A54" />
    <stroke android:color="#00000000" android:width="1dp" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" />
</shape>
```